# Why is "rm -r" unable to delete this folder?

Tags: linux, permissions, rm

I have a folder with `-wx` permissions called `folder1` and another folder inside it called `folder2` with `rwx` permissions.

I tried to delete `folder1` using this command:

```
rm -r folder1
```

But I got the following error:

```
rm: cannot remove 'folder1': Permission denied
```

The reason I think I got this error is because the `rm` program needs to first get the content of `folder1` (get the names of the files and folders inside `folder1` that is) in order to be able to delete that content (because you can't delete a file or folder without knowing its name I think), and then the `rm` program can delete `folder1` itself.

But since `folder1` doesn't have the `read` permission, then the `rm` program can't get its content, and hence it can't delete its content, and since it can't delete its content, then it can't delete it.

Am I correct?

Comment: Do "ls -l" and tell us what the permissions of the DIRECTORY are.

Answer (score 19):

I think your analysis is correct: you cannot delete the directory since its non-empty, and you cannot empty it since you cannot see its contents.

I just gave it a try:

```
$ mkdir -p folder1/folder2
$ chmod -r folder1
$ rm -rf folder1
rm: cannot remove 'folder1': Permission denied
$ rmdir folder1/folder2
$ rm -rf folder1
$
```

When I wrote “you”, I meant any program you may run. Your `rm -r` command first sees that `folder1` is a directory, so it tries to discover its contents to empty it, but fails for missing read permission, then it tries to delete it but fails because it’s non-empty. The “Permission denied” is misleading; I think “Directory not empty” (like `rmdir` reports) would be more appropriate.)

Comment: It can't report `Directory not empty` in this case since it would not know it was empty or not. You would still get the same error when trying to delete an _empty_ directory that you don't have read permissions on. (Also, please disregard my previous comment, I didn't have my thinking cap on).

Comment: @Kusalananda That sounds sane, but ``rmdir`` is able to report “Directory not empty”. And if you read my test, you’ll see that it accepts to remove the ``folder1`` directory, **with no read permission**, once I have emptied it.

Comment: Your test shows an interesting difference between our systems. I get a `Permission denied` when trying to `rm -r folder1` when it's empty. I'm on OpenBSD, not Linux.

Comment: @Kusalananda That’s interesting. I would have thought that this behavior was specified by the Single Unix Specification, so that Linux and {Free,Net,Open}BSD would behave identically. (For the record, I am using Debian Stretch 9.8 with a linux 4.9.144-3 x86_64 kernel.)

Comment: Hmm... The only thing that POSIX says is that if the operand is a directory and `-r` is used, each directory entry (except for `.` and `..`) should be removed as if they were a file operand of `rm -r`. It appears as if GNU `rm` simply does a `rmdir()` on the directory if it's not readable, because it will have no way to get the contents of it.

Comment: @Kusalananda But can you ``rmdir`` the empty folder if you have no read permission?

Comment: Yes, and this is not disallowed as far as I know.

Comment: @Kusalananda Ok, then I like the behavior of GNU better: I would expect ``rm -r`` to succeed whenever ``rmdir`` does.

Answer (score 7):

For deletion to occur the system must be able to read the contents and identify what has to be deleted.

I've tried simulating what you are attempting :

```
[vagrant@desktop1 ~]$ sudo rm -rf folder1/ && mkdir -pv folder1/folder2 && sudo chmod 333 -v folder1/ && sudo chmod 777 -v folder1/folder2
mkdir: created directory 'folder1'
mkdir: created directory 'folder1/folder2'
mode of 'folder1/' changed from 0775 (rwxrwxr-x) to 0333 (-wx-wx-wx)
mode of 'folder1/folder2' changed from 0775 (rwxrwxr-x) to 0777 (rwxrwxrwx)
[vagrant@desktop1 ~]$ ls -lh
total 0
d-wx-wx-wx. 3 vagrant vagrant 21 Feb 24 10:40 folder1
[vagrant@desktop1 ~]$
```

If we try deleting without read permissions it fails:

```
[vagrant@desktop1 ~]$ rm -r folder1/
rm: cannot remove 'folder1/': Permission denied
[vagrant@desktop1 ~]$ sudo chmod +r folder1/
[vagrant@desktop1 ~]$ rm -r folder1/
[vagrant@desktop1 ~]$
```

In an strace for the two attempts the difference is that the directory contents cannot be read (getdents):

```
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "folder1/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0333, st_size=21, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "folder1/", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
geteuid()                               = 1000
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "folder1/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0333, st_size=21, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "folder1/", W_OK)   = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "folder1/", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "folder1/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0333, st_size=21, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
```

With read permissions:

```
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "folder1/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=21, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "folder1/", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=21, ...}) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x38800 (flags O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW)
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getdents(3, /* 3 entries */, 32768)     = 80
close(3)                                = 0
geteuid()                               = 1000
```

To conclude even if you  own a directory and it has the executable bit, you still need read permissions so that you may see its contents and delete the folder. It's not the same for a file though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't have enough reputation to comment on the answer by ttaran7, so it looks like an answer it will have to be. My up-vote isn't publicly visible either, due to low reputation. I up voted that answer for actually including a system call trace, rather than just speculation.

*To answer the OP's question: Yes, your reasoning was correct: You get blocked at the failure to read the directory*

I ran a similar trace to what they (ttaran7) had done because I suspected the same reasoning: The `rm` call would fail upon failing to read the directory and that would be the end of that, no chance to complain about the directory being empty. Upon taking a second look at the trace that I took, I noticed that a system call was made to attempt to unlink the provided filename anyway:

```
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "folder1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0311, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "folder1", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "folder1", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "folder1", AT_REMOVEDIR) = -1 ENOTEMPTY (Directory not empty)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2995, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2995
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=45256, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 45256, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f8db25ca000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale- langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=578, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 578, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f8db25c9000
close(3)                                = 0
write(2, "rm: ", 4rm: )                     = 4
write(2, "cannot remove 'folder1'", 23cannot remove 'folder1') = 23
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_AU/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2893, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2893, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f8db25c8000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, ": Permission denied", 19: Permission denied)     = 19
write(2, "\n", 1
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exitgroup(1)
```

Look at the 4th line: `unlinkat`... which fails because the directory is NOT empty. Now that is what I would consider unexpected behaviour, the fact it tries to delete the directory at all, despite not having read permissions that is.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I'll correct that when I get to a real keyboard. Thanks.